# Access remote `/dev/input/` on local machine

Tags: ssh, ubuntu, remote, joystick

My robot needs to read input commands from a USB joystick which is physically connected to a remote desktop (Ubuntu). On desktop, the joystick is available for local user with permissions:

```
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root input 13, 0 ** /dev/input/js0
```

Using `sshfs` on robot, I mounted remote `/dev/input/` on a local folder `/dev/input/remote/`:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other DESKTOP_USR@DESKTOP_IP:/dev/input /dev/input/remote
```

This allows me to find the controller `js0` on the robot:

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root netdev 0, 0 ** /dev/input/remote/js0
```

However, none of the programs on the robot (including `sudo jstest /dev/input/remote/js0`) can open/use this device. It throws **Permission Denied** error!

**How can I find access to remote Joystick on the robot without permission issues?**

MORE: users on both sides are added to `FUSE` and `NETDEV` groups. Also, I have added line `user_allow_other` to `/etc/fuse.conf` which is required for `allow_other` argument in SSHFS command. No success.